# use enum instead of switch to get the correspond class

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I have two classes namely `classA` and `classB` which both inherit from `class1`.

Now I want to send a string like "A" based on that I should instantiate class A

My boss asked me to use `enum` instead of using switch case to write the code.

How do i go about writing this.

Comment: Does your boss mean he wants you to use an enum in place of a string to select the type to instantiate?

Comment: enum option{A=new classA(),B= new classB()}

string v = "A";

new option.get(v);


can't I write something like this?

Comment: FWIW, most IoC containers (and the P&P common service locator) support GetInstance with a key, so while it would be overkill for a single Factory, this might be worth having an IoC container deal with?  http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a lookup factory

```
_map = new Dictionary<Option, Func<Class1>>();

_map.Add(Option.A, () => new ClassA());
_map.Add(Option.B, () => new ClassB());
```

An then in the resolve to get the correct class

```
public Class1 Resolve(Option option)
{
   Func<Class1> result;
   if(_map.TryGetValue(option, out result))
      return result();
   else
      return null;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your boss is asking you to use an enum inside the switch statement:

```
MyClassEnum classToCreate = MyClassEnum.ClassA;
switch(classToCreate)
{
    case MyClassEnum.ClassA:
        return new ClassA();
    case MyClassEnum.ClassB:
        return new ClassB();
}
```

If you include the section of code which does the test and creates the objects, we can probably provide more guidance.

Comment: enum option{A=new classA(),B= new classB()}

string v = "A";

new option.get(v);


can't I write something like this?

my boss just said "Do not use switch" ,so I think I can't use it at all.

Comment: Unfortunately enums can't do what you're asking. You might have to seek clarification from your boss.  There are various solutions to this, but none will perform much (or any) better than a switch, and most will cause problems for anyone looking at the code in the future.  It's easy to understand the intent of the switch.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public class Class1
{
    public enum class1: {classA, classB}
    public static Class1 Make(class1 which)
    {
        switch (which)
        {
             case classA: return new ClassA();
             case classB: return new ClassB();
             default: return null;
        }
    }
 }


 public class ClassA: Class1 {}
 public class ClassA: Class1 {}
```

Comment: enum option{A=new classA(),B= new classB()}

string v = "A";

new option.get(v);


can't I write something like this?

my boss just said "Do not use switch" ,so I think I can't use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid switch, you could always keep a lookup of some sort, something like one of these:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Class1 { }

class ClassA : Class1 { }
class ClassB : Class1 { }

class Program
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _typeMap =
        new Dictionary<string, Type>
        {
            { "A", typeof(ClassA) }, 
            { "B", typeof(ClassB) }, 
        };

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<Class1>> _funcMap =
        new Dictionary<string, Func<Class1>>
        {
            { "A", () => new ClassA() }, 
            { "B", () => new ClassB() }, 
        };

    Class1 CreateViaTypeMap(string typeName)
    {
        var type = _typeMap[typeName];
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Class1;
    }

    Class1 CreateViaFuncMap(string typeName)
    {
        var func = _funcMap[typeName];
        return func();
    }
}
```